# Unable to deserialize ArrayList of ALL objects - only the first object is deserialized

Tags: java, deserialization

There is lots of java serialization/deserialization questions, but I couldn't find the answer to my problem. I run the GUI and three *music* objects are stored in ArrayList at run-time (pre-coded):

```
private ArrayList<Music> musicList = new ArrayList<Music>();
...
musicList.add(new Music("Metallica", "Master of Puppets"));
```

Then I add some more music from GUI. Those new objects are also added to the ArrayList `musicList` (I can verify that by looping through the `musicList`).
I can then serialize this `ArrayList`, open the `music.ser` file with notepad and see all those objects in there. But I can't find a way to deserialize all of them objects - all I get back after deserialization are those objects added at run-time plus the first one added from GUI. The other objects added from GUI are never deserialized. I don't know whether I suppose to check that `music.ser` file using a loop or buffer (I found similar suggestions)? Any help will be highly appreciated. Here are lines of my code I believe are important for that question:

```
private ArrayList<Music> musicList;

...

musicList = new ArrayList<Music>();
musicList.add(new Music("Metallica", "Master of Puppets"));
musicList.add(new Music("Pantera", "Far Beyond Driven"));
musicList.add(new Music("Kognitif", "Soul Food"));

...

// serialization method
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("music.ser", true);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(musicList);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
    for (Music m : musicList) {
        System.out.println("AddMusic: " + m);
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}

// deserialization method
ArrayList<Music> musicList2 = new ArrayList<Music>();
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("music.ser");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    musicList2 = (ArrayList<Music>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    fis.close();                
    for (Music m : musicList2) {
        System.out.println("Reading Music: \n" + m.getArtist() + " - " + m.getAlbum());
    }               

    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is Music.java class (although I think it should be assumed this one is properly coded):

```
public class Music implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String artist;
    private String album;
    JTextArea textArea;

    public Music(String artist, String album) {
        super();
        this.artist = artist;
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return artist + " - " + album + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than default serilaVersionUid use a generated version UID and also remove the toString() method and give it a try.

Comment: Doesn't work either. I don't see why would it, to be honest.

Comment: @mahadevkalyansrikanth What are your reasons for those pointless recommendations?

Comment: 'Added from GUI' how? And why does `Music` have a `JTextArea` field? Are you expecting that to be serialized and deserialized and to magically appear somewhere in the GUI? It won't. I doubt it should be there at all, but if it should it should certainly be `volatile`.

Comment: @user207421: Added from GUI by entering the artist and the album into JTextFields. The JTextArea in Music class is there by mistake - I forgot to delete it after copying some code. And I don't expect it to magically appear in the GUI. All I want is to deserialize all the objects from the .ser file. I'll know what to do with them then.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the file.  Initially i tried with the music.ser and created a GUI and tried to add two artists from the GUI, along with the three artists which you have provided above.

I tried to serialize and deserialize them and it went well. Later i tried to add another element from GUI and whiletry to serialize and deserialize i found that it is not serializing properly.

Later i changed the file name to test.ser and when i tried to add three artists from the GUI and three from runtime everything worked fine and when i tried to add the fourth one from GUI it failed again.

All that you need to do is delete the file if existed and create a new one while serializing and deserializing.

Sample code attached.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


    public class TestGUI {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            final ArrayList<Music> musicList = new ArrayList<Music>();

            //Creating the Frame
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Frame");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);

            //Creating the MenuBar and adding components
            JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu m1 = new JMenu("FILE");
            JMenu m2 = new JMenu("Help");
            mb.add(m1);
            mb.add(m2);
            JMenuItem m11 = new JMenuItem("Open");
            JMenuItem m22 = new JMenuItem("Save as");
            m1.add(m11);
            m1.add(m22);

            //Creating the panel at bottom and adding components
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // the panel is not visible in output
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Artist");
            final JTextField tf = new JTextField(10); // accepts upto 10 characters
            JLabel album = new JLabel("Enter Album");
            final JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(10);
            JButton send = new JButton("Send");
            JButton reset = new JButton("Serialize");
            panel.add(label); // Components Added using Flow Layout
            panel.add(label); // Components Added using Flow Layout
            panel.add(tf);
            panel.add(album); // Components Added using Flow Layout
            panel.add(tf1);
            panel.add(send);
            panel.add(reset);

            send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    Music m = new Music(tf.getText(), tf1.getText());
                    musicList.add(m);
                    tf1.setText("");
                    tf.setText("");

                }
            });

            reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try { 

                    TestSerialization.serializeAndDeserialize(musicList);
                    } catch (Exception ex) { 

                    }
                }
            });

            //Adding Components to the frame.
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, mb);

            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Sample Music (same as yours)

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Music implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String artist;
    private String album;
    JTextArea textArea;

    public Music(String artist, String album) {
        super();
        this.artist = artist;
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return artist + " - " + album + "\n";
    }
}
```

Sample serialization class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class TestSerialization {


    public static ArrayList<Music> serializeAndDeserialize(ArrayList<Music> musicList) throws Exception { 

        musicList.add(new Music("Metallica", "Master of Puppets"));
        musicList.add(new Music("Pantera", "Far Beyond Driven"));
        musicList.add(new Music("Kognitif", "Soul Food"));

        // serialization method
        try {
            File f = new File("test.ser");
            if (f.exists()) { 
                f.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.ser", true);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(musicList);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
            for (Music m : musicList) {
                System.out.println("AddMusic: " + m);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        // deserialization method
        ArrayList<Music> musicList2 = new ArrayList<Music>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            musicList2 = (ArrayList<Music>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();                
            for (Music m : musicList2) {
                System.out.println("Reading Music: \n" + m.getArtist() + " - " + m.getAlbum());
            }               

            }
         catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return musicList2;
    }

}
```

Comment: He doesn't need the `exists()/delete()` code. He just needs to get rid of the append parameter `true` when constructing the `FileOutputStream`. You can't append to object streams.

Comment: @mahadev kalyan srikanth: Thank you. Appreciate that.